# Problems fitting arbitray distributions using the fitdistplus package

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I am trying to fit my data using the `fitdist()` function from the fitdistrplus package in R. I succeeded using a normal and a lognormal distribution via key words `'norm'` and `'lnorm'` which I found via searching online.

I was not able to get other distributions working; the help of `fitdist()` says:

> distr: A character string "name" naming a distribution for which the corresponding density function dname, the corresponding distribution function pname and the corresponding quantile function qname must be defined, or directly the density function.

I checked and when entering `?norm` or `?norm` into the R command line, neither function `norm()` nor `lnorm()` is found. This confuses me totally.

When I try for example `fitdist(data, 'poisson')`, I get the following error message:

`Error in fitdist(data$time, "poisson") : 
  The  dpoisson  function must be defined`

I am somewhat a noob in R, can anybody give a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`norm()` in `R` is a different function to compute norms of a matrix, so not directly related to the normal distribution.

`?Normal` brings up the documentation related to the normal distribution, and you'll see the 4 functions `dnorm`, `pnorm`, `qnorm` and `rnorm` belonging to this family.

If you look at `?Lognormal` you'll see the same convention with the typical 4 functions.

More generally, you can look-up `?Distributions`, which links all of them. There you can see that the keyword for the poisson distribution should actually be `pois`.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure: `fitdist(data,'norm')` is the correct syntax to fit Gaussian parameters right? I do not get: Why do I have to look for `?Normal` to get results as `dnorm` etc. As said, I am an R noob...

Comment: That syntax is correct, yes. You can also do `?dnorm` or `?rnorm`, these will bring up the same page as `?Normal`